# components required when creating new App for Office 2013 project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, office-app

Using VS 2012 , when I create **App for Office 2013** , it's show me this error .

[image]

Using [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2013/03/06/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012-now-available.aspx) , I've install Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 .
How can I fix this ? Where can I download required components ?
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to install the

- [Microsoft Exchange Webservices Managed API 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35371)

To install the Web Developer Tools you should modify your Visual Studio installation and install the feature:

[image: Web Developer Tools]

Comment: Done @jessehouwing , but Same Error :(